# Linking users and avatar urls to each other within same promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, promise

need some help. From firebase I collect all my users I get an object array containing key value pairs. To this object I want to add another key value pair:

```
avatarUrl: 'someurl'
```

Then I want to dispatch this to my reducer.

I am a bit stuck at combining the two, here is how far I got:

```
const collectionRef = dbf.collection('users');
const collectionArray = [];
collectionRef.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let withId = {
                docId: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
            };
            collectionArray.push(withId);

            storageRef.child(`${doc.id}/avatar.jpg`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                withId = {
                    ...withId,
                    avatarUrl: url,
                };
                collectionArray.push(withId);
            });
        });
        return dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.DONE,
            data: collectionArray,
        });
    })
```

I have a promise within a promise and stuff just doesn't seem to go well.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give this a try

```
const collectionRef = dbf.collection('users');
const storageRef = /*...*/

// getAvatarUrl :: String -> Promise String 
const getAvatarUrl = userId =>
  storageRef
    .child(`${userId}/avatar.jpg`)
    .getDownloadURL()

// addDocIdAndAvatar :: Doc -> Promise {docId, ...docData, avatarUrl}
const addDocIdAndAvatar = async doc => ({
  docId: doc.id,
  ...doc.data(),
  avatarUrl: await getAvatarUrl(doc.id)
});

// collectUsersFromSnapshot :: Snapshot -> Dispatch
const collectUsersFromSnapshot = await snapshot =>
  dispatch({
    type: actionTypes.DONE,
    data: await Promise.all(snapshot.map(addDocIdAndAvatar)),
  });

collectionRef.get()
  .then(collectUsersFromSnapshot)
```

By using an `async` function for `addDocIdAndAvatar`, we can `await` the `avatarUrl`. Similarly, in `collectUsersFromSnapshot` we first map over the collection of users in the snapshot with `addDocIdAndAvatar`, a Promise, then use `Promise.all` to `await` the resolution of the entire collection of promises into an array of resolutions, which we then pass to `dispatch`.

If your setup prohibits modern JS features like `async` functions, you can use this equivalent fluent version:

```
const collectionRef = dbf.collection('users');
const storageRef = /*...*/

// getAvatarUrl :: String -> Promise String 
const getAvatarUrl = userId =>
  storageRef
    .child(`${userId}/avatar.jpg`)
    .getDownloadURL()

// addDocIdAndAvatar :: Doc -> Promise {docId, ...docData, avatarUrl}
const addDocIdAndAvatar = doc => 
  getAvatarUrl(doc.id)
    .then(avatarUrl => ({ docId: doc.id, ...doc.data(), avatarUrl }))

// dispatchUsers :: [User] -> Dispatch
const dispatchUsers = data =>
  dispatch({ type: actionTypes.DONE, data })

// collectUsersFromSnapshot :: Snapshot -> Promise Dispatch
const collectUsersFromSnapshot = snapshot =>
  Promise.all(snapshot.map(addDocIdAndAvatar))
    .then(dispatchUsers)

collectionRef.get()
  .then(collectUsersFromSnapshot)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering benny, I am not familiar with async await (should dive in to that) somehow I get a complile error at await snapshot => dispatch({.......

Comment: in that case your build step doesn't support async functions, which is a shame. I'll make a version that uses fluent flows, hold tight.

Comment: only a tip to understand async/await: 
async function returns a promise, 
await keyword is a `.then` and in case of error, `try/catch` is the `.catch`

Answer (score 0):

@BennyPowers thanks I managed to solve it thanks to your code. snapshot isnt an array, the user array is only formed after making the collection array. So had to alter it a bit but the end result is : Does this make sense for asnyc development ?

```
const collectionRef = dbf.collection('users');
const collectionArray = [];
collectionRef.get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let withId = {
                docId: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
            };
            collectionArray.push(withId);

            storageRef.child(`${doc.id}/avatar.jpg`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                withId = {
                    ...withId,
                    avatarUrl: url,
                };
                collectionArray.push(withId);
            });
        });

        const getAvatarUrl = userId => storageRef
            .child(`${userId}/avatar.jpg`)
            .getDownloadURL();

        const addDocIdAndAvatar = doc => getAvatarUrl(doc.docId)
            .then(avatarUrl => ({ ...doc, avatarUrl }));

        const dispatchUsers = data => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.DONE, data });
        Promise.all(collectionArray.map(addDocIdAndAvatar))
            .then(dispatchUsers);
    });
```

Comment: if snapshot isn't an array, how do you get a `forEach` instance method?